# In apple mail, with contact photos enabled next to mail subjects, one person in my contact doesn't have his picture show up

Tags: macos, mail.app

In Apple mail for OSX, I have pictures enabled for both the mail list view as well as in the message itself. This works fairly well, grabbing pictures from my contacts except for one person. Their picture doesn't show up and I don't know what makes them unique.

When I click on their name and select "Show Contact Card" it shows their picture. I can't understand what conditions would cause that picture to not show up in the mail itself.

Comment: How did you add the picture for this one contact?

Comment: @myhd It was automatically ported over from my iPhone by taking a picture with the camera.

Comment: Hmmm... difficult! You could inspect the contents of the Contact with a text editor. In Contacts, click and hold the desired contact until a small vcard icon appears, then drag to the Desktop — a .vcf file appears. Then open it with your favorite text editor and look for "PHOTO;" ➝ how do the following lines look like?

Comment: Looks like every other contact. PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG: followed by the actual encoded image.

Comment: Have you tried to delete, then re-import the contact?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have the contact's email address duplicated in another contact.

Comment: I can't confirm this Im afraid